# How to start doing highcharts spline updating each seconds? Step by step guide please

Tags: php, json, highcharts, live, spline

I have problems and difficulties on how to start and do the spline updating each seconds live graph, I did my researched already but still cannot find any solutions to help my current situation. I need to update my data every seconds, I'm using php and I hope someone can guide me along.

1. Is there a way not to use ajax when loading JSON data to my live graph?

Answer (score 0):

Please consider this example http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-update. Only what you need is print in php  and then in javascript get correct value from json (instead of using Math.rand()). Then you can avoid of using ajax.

Comment: Hey Sebastian, I'm using highcharts spline update which is the graph you referring to. I tried using json with the graph but it's still does not display my database data correctly. I removed the Math.random() and replaced it with 0.

Comment: In case when you have 0 values, what is the purpose of getting data from database? Could you paste your full code?

Comment: @Sebastian I am trying it with asp.net but not getting success and you guide me to any example?